# Generic Mapping Tools: Weird lines created by pscoast

Tags: mac, gmt

I'm creating maps using the Generic Mapping Tools (GMT) from the University of Hawaii. I get weird vertical and horizontal lines using `pscoast`. This is the command to reproduce the problem:

```
gmt pscoast -JM18c -R43/62/35/49 -G50/255/50 -Df -P > caspiansea.ps
convert -density 300 caspiansea.ps caspiansea.png
```

The lines are already present in the ps file, so the last step (`convert`) does not introduce the problem. It happens across all areas, the caspian sea area is just an example.

This is the image that's created by those commands:
[image]

Version: GMT 5.2.1 (the most recent version provided by Macports) on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the problem. I assumed that the lines were already in the `.ps` file. This was a mistake. Double-clicking the `.ps` file on MacOS opens `Preview` that on-the-fly converts PS to PDF and in that PDF the strange lines were visible. The same thing seems to happen when using `convert` from ImageMagick.

Using `gmt psconvert` though does not create those weird lines. So, there must be something strange happening in converting from PS to something else when not using the GMT tools.

Why did I use `convert` in the first place? TBH I don't know ...